# static html page in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, static

I'm building a fairly simple experiment to run as a website.
It's all javascript, so all I need the server for is to store the experiment results. I've set up a Django server on WebFaction, but my problem is making django redirect clients to the 1st static html page (from where js takes over).

I gather my solution should be something like this (using django 1.7.1):

**urls.py**

```
django.views.generic import RedirectView  

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view (url='fudge.html'))
)
```

It works when `DEBUG = True` on **settings.py**, but when it's set to `False` I get:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /fudge.html was not found on this server.
```

Iv'e set `STATIC_ROOT = '/AmirStatic/'` in **settings.py** and ran `python manage.py collectstatic` following instructions iv'e found on the net, but this didn't do the Trick.
Either I don't understand the path settings in Django or they are not configured properly or I don't understand how static webpages are used. But I would have thought it would be much simpler than this.  Iv'e spent a good 3 days losing hair over it.

I would be very thankful to anyone with good advice on this,
thanks a lot in advance.

Oh and i'm a newbie to python, Django and web-developing in general if that hasn't come across :)

Comment: But what is serving /fudge.html?

Comment: Why are you using ``RedirectView.as_view (url='fudge.html'))`` instead of an actual URL? you are now specifying a template

Comment: When you set DEBUG = False django stops serving your static files, so you need to configure your reverse proxy for that (or whatever you want to serve them). I have worked with nginx only, but in there i have to tell nginx where the static and media folders are located so it can serve them. I don't know what they use on WebFaction.

Comment: If you go to /AmirStatic/fudge.html , do you get a valid response?  (If not, you should at least be getting an error from your front end server instead of django).  You might have two problems: configuring your view to point to a static URL, and then getting your web server to server static content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are developing, Django can serve your statics files, but when going into production, django doesn't serve your static files (and should not, it should be handled by your reverse proxy such as nginx or apache)

Please take a look at the [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/deployment/) of the django documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mihai Zamfir suggested above-- try actually using a URL and linking to a view. Then within the view you define the logic for the template which is contained in `fudge.html`.

Example:

```
url(r'^fudge/$', views.fudge_view, name='fudge')
```

This is assuming you also have in your `urls.py`:

```
from your_app_name import views
```